# Values changing in class?

Tags: c++

I assign a with "abc", b with "def", add them together and a changes. I want a to stay as abc. instead its "abcdef". C is the only value that should be "abcdef". What am I doing wrong here?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    class String {
    public:
        void print();
        String operator=(const String& Other)
        {       
            message = Other.message;
            return *this;
        }
        String operator+(const String& Other)const
        {
            return String(strcat(message, Other.message));
        }
        String operator+=(const String& Other)
        {

        }
        String(char* def = "Default")
        {
            message = new char[strlen(def) + 1];
            strcpy(message, doub);
        }
        String(const String &obj)
        {
            message = obj.message;
        }
        ~String();
    private:
        char * message;
    };
    void String::print()
    {
        cout << message;
    }
    String::~String(void) {

        cout << "Object is being deleted" << endl;
    }


    // Main function for the program
    int main() {
        String a("abc");
        String b("def");
        String c;
        c = a + b;
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `strcat` which basically appends `Other.message` to your `message` memory block. You can read about this in [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)

To fix your issue you can make something like :

```
return String(strcat(strcat(str.message, this->message), Other.message))
```

[online verification](http://rextester.com/ZFAR48485)

Answer (score 1):

"abc" and "def" are C-string read-only literals, which are stored in executable in read-only section, and later is mapped to read-only memory.

When you are using `strcat`, you are invoking undefined behavior, as you are trying to modify "abc" value.

Correct way here is to allocate memory in constructor and strcpy value of argument to internal allocated pointer. And later - in operator+ you shall re-allocate such pointer to allow more memory.

Answer (score 0):

You have *multiple* problems with the class, most of them stemming from your use of the pointer `message`.

One thing is, for example, the `operator+` function which calls `strcat` using the pointer, without reallocating the memory it points to so it will fit the old *and* new string.

And you really *can't* reallocate the pointer, because you don't really own the data your pointer is pointing to. Prominent example: You assignment operator copies *the pointer* and not the string it points to. That means you will have two `String` objects both pointing to the same memory.

You also have no destructor, so each `String` object you create will lead to a *memory leak*. However just adding a destructor that deletes the memory is not enough, unless you fix the pointer-copying.